# use .length to define the end of a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

When trying to work with loops in javascript I'm facing an error saying:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')

I guess the problem is related to how I define the end of the loop using .length

This is the code I'm trying:

```
let els = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
{
    els = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[i].innerText
    console.log(els);
}
```

Trying to debug it, I looked for the exact length and format of els.length and the result is:

format=number
value=6

If I change the end of the loop (see below) I don't get that error anymore:

```
let els = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    els = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[i].innerText
    console.log(els);
}
```

Comment: Initially `els` is an array-like list of elements.  Then, els becomes the text of element i.  The problem with that is the for loop relies on `els` being an arraylike list in order to read its `.length` property.  I suggest you create a new variable to store/display the innerText.

Comment: You're re-assigning your `els` variable inside the loop. Doing so will change the value of `els.length`, which is what your loop is based on. The first instance is enumerating the number of elements with that class name. The second instance (inside the loop) is counting the number of characters in a string (due to innertext property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the `els` twice. At the end of each loop, it checks if `i < els.length` but you have made `els` a string so `els.length` is different.

You should name the second `els` differently.